# NGINX proxy_pass to RabbitMQ manager only works via mobile device

Tags: docker, nginx, rabbitmq, docker-compose, rancher

I'm encountering a very specific problem with my NGINX/RabbitMQ setup in which the desired result is only accesible via a mobile device. I hope there is someone who could shine a light on what i'm doing wrong :). I have the following setup:

Two droplets on DigitalOcean:

- Droplet A with rancher server installed on it
- Droplet B which acts as a host, controlled by rancher. **for this example, assume its ip-adress is 123.45.678.90**

Two images on docker-hub:

- myaccount/customnginx
- myaccount/customrabbitmq

**myaccount/customnginx**

*Dockerfile*:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

*nginx.conf (in which http://123.45.678.90:15672 = Droplet B + RabbitMQ port)*

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        server_name www.mydomain.nl mydomain.nl;

        access_log /dev/stdout;

        location /rabbitmq/ {
            proxy_pass http://123.45.678.90:15672/;  
            rewrite ^/rabbitmq$ /rabbitmq/ permanent;
            rewrite ^/rabbitmq/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_buffering                    off;
            proxy_set_header Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }


}
```

**myaccount/customrabbitmq**

I can provide the rabbitMQ configuration upon request, but I don't think it is of much importance at the moment.

**Both images are built into a stack on Rancher via the following docker-compose.yml**:

```
version: '2'

services:
    rabbitmq:
        image: myaccount/customrabbitmq
        ports:
            - 5672:5672
            - 15672:15672
    nginx:
        image: myaccount/customproxy
        ports:
            - 80:80
```

[which looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozlkK.png)

**Now**

When I try to access my RabbitMQ manager via www.mydomain.nl/rabbitmq **on a mobile device** everything works properly. When I try to do the same with any browser on my desktop (or laptop), nothing works. I don't even see the attempt logged on Rancher (nginx container). I also tried this in incognito-mode and/or with ad-block-plus/Disconnect disabled, but to no avail.

What's wrong with this configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As u said, the only difference between a mobile and a laptop is the network they are connecting, could u plz put more information on that?

Comment: All devices were on the same wifi-network while trying to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I managed to fix this. Either or both of the following had to do something with it:

- I enabled connection through ipv6 on the DigitalOcean droplet, added the ipv6 adress as AAAA record (for both the www.mydomain.nl as mydomain.nl) in the DNS-records with the domain registrar. I don't know much about this subject, but thought the mobile device might have connected with ipv4, while desktop tried to connect with the other (which wasn't set-up properly). I went into the firefox ocnfig (*type about:config in adress bar*) and set network.dns.disableIPv6 to true. This seemed to help.
- I waited a day. Maybe it took a little longer for the DNS (normal A-records) to propagate properly

Comment: The second way you did may make no affect on issue. Since the DNS server you used on both mobile and laptop are the same one.